# FTP in C# returning corrupted file, why?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, ftp

I have this method to transfer files using a FTP Server:

```
private void TransferNeededFiles(IEnumerable<string> filenames)
{
    foreach (var filename in filenames)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(@"ftp://{0}/{1}".Fill(Config.ServerUri, filename))) as FtpWebRequest;

        if (request != null)
        {
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Config.Username, Config.Password);

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var fileStream = new FileStream(@"{0}/{1}".Fill(Config.DestinationFolderPath, filename), FileMode.Create);

                var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
                writer.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();

                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A .gz file, included in the list of filenames, is always corrupted. When I try to copy from ftp using windows explorer, the file is not corrupted. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: Are you sure you are using binary transfer and not ascii?

Comment: I am using this code above. I don't specify neither ascii or binary, could this be the problem?

Comment: Check out UseBinary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usebinary.aspx as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
writer.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
```

`StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` returns a Unicode encoded string.  You want something that will read the stream byte for byte.

Comment: I think Joel's nailed it (as usual). You will probably want to read the stream in chunks also instead of all at once.

Answer (score 3):

`Reader`s and `Writer`s work with Unicode characters. To transfer binary data you want to be working with raw bytes, so you should be using plain `Stream`s. You can copy from one stream to another with a loop like the following:

```
BufferedStream inputStream, outputStream;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;

while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

A good thing about this is that it will also only use a fixed amount of memory rather than reading the entire file into memory at once.